# Protecting images from direct access by checking current PHP session with mod_rewrite

Tags: php, session, mod-rewrite, authorization, rewritemap

I'm working on a solution to a problem where users could potentially access images (in this case PDF files) stored in a folder off the server root.   Normally, my application validates users through PHP scripts and sessions.  What isn't happening right now is preventing non-logged in users from potentially accessing the PDFs.

The solution I'm looking for would (I think) need to be tied in with Apache.  I saw an interesting solution using RewriteMap & RewriteRule, however the example involved putting this in an .htaccess file in the PDF directory.   Can't do that with Apache (error: RewriteMap not allowed here).  I believe the rewrite directives need to go in my httpd.conf, which I have access to.

So the example I found (that resulted in 'rewritemap not allowed here') is here:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteMap auth prg:auth.php
RewriteRule (.*) ${auth:$1}

auth.php just checks PHP session and redirects to a login script if needed.

I'm reading that I have to place this in my httpd.conf.  How would I specify that the RewriteMap should only occur on a specific directory (including subdirectories)?

Comment: Borrowing from the MVC pattern, you could redirect all requests to a bootstrap file and then depending on the permissions you could either load the requested file or a default file.

Comment: @Moses - that's what I'm more or less going for here.  I haven't had time to research/test apache configs since posting my question - so I'm still stuck on how to correctly redirect traffic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st, be sure that you have to put that directly in httpd.conf. On Debian system, for instance, you have 1 file by virtualhost (a virtualhost usually is a website)
So, you have to put your rewriteMap in a "directory" like this:

```
<Directory /full/path/to/your/pdfs>
    RewriteEngine on
    ...
</Directory>
```